# Trouble passing values to a second layout

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop my first Android app. It is simple enough in theory: user enters 2 values, the app does some calculations and returns with a few results in a second layout.

Here is my MainActivity.

```
package domain.com.myapp;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                doCalculations();
            }
        });
    }

    void doCalculations() {
        Log.i("info", "In doCalculations");

        // get inputs
        final EditText editSPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText editPPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        // do calculations

        float salePrice = Float.valueOf(editSPrice.getText().toString());
        float purchPrice = Float.valueOf(editPPrice.getText().toString());

        // set outputs ** this is where I'm stuck!! **
        textView9.setText(String.format("%.2f", salePrice));
        textView10.setText(String.format("%.2f", purchPrice));

        setContentView(R.layout.the_quote);

    }
}
```

The problem is that textView9 and textView10 are out of scope (in the second layout, the_quote), and I'm not sure what to change.

Comment: Use Intent to pass values into another Activity

Answer (score 2):

In your current Activity, create a new `Intent:`

```
String value="Hello world";
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);    
i.putExtra("key",value);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String value = extras.getString("key");

}
```

This is how to pass values between Activities

Comment: Thanks Jimale. I think that's part of my problem that I don't have a second Activity, and I need to create one.

Comment: Create the Second Activity with its Xml layout after that use Intent

Answer (score 1):

```
It's Simple use intent to pass value from layout to another

On the sender side, use

Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", intValue);
startActivity(myIntent);

On the receiver side, use

Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int intValue = mIntent.getFloatExtra("intVariableName");
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android to pass value to second `activity` you can simply use `putExtra` method.

In your first activity add:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
i.putExtra("name", value);
startActivity(I);
```

And in your second activity get it:

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing your layout using setContentView(...), you need to initialise view inside it again.

I would recommended [Jimale Abdi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56439183/11555065)

But you can also try below solution for now,

```
   void doCalculations() {
        Log.i("info", "In doCalculations");

        // get inputs
        final EditText editSPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText editPPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        // do calculations

        float salePrice = Float.valueOf(editSPrice.getText().toString());
        float purchPrice = Float.valueOf(editPPrice.getText().toString());

        Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);    
        i.putExtra("salePrice",salePrice);
        i.putExtra("purchPrice",purchPrice);
        startActivity(i);

        //setContentView(R.layout.the_quote);

        // Find your view again from updated layout...
        //final TextView textView9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        //final TextView textView10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);

        //textView9.setText(String.format("%.2f", salePrice));
        //textView10.setText(String.format("%.2f", purchPrice));

   }
```

Then in second activity retrieve as below in onCreate method,

```
        final TextView textView9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        final TextView textView10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
          Float salePrice = extras.getFloat("salePrice");
          Float purchPrice = extras.getFloat("purchPrice");

          textView9.setText(String.format("%.2f", salePrice));
          textView10.setText(String.format("%.2f", purchPrice));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Your temporary measure works fine. But you're right I do need to do it properly as there are many more than just the 2 textView's. I think my doCalculations() probably belongs in the second Activity.

Comment: Nope, You can do calculation on first activity and send result to other activity.

Comment: @Greum Check updated code with passing value in intent.